# Is an epoxide opening more favorable than a chloride leaving in the same molecule?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

In general, we've learned that alkoxide groups are awful leaving groups, unless we're talking about epoxide rings whose ring strain allow the alkoxide to act as a leaving group in a ring-opening reaction. However, if a structure contained both an epoxide and a relatively good leaving group like Chloride, what would predominate if a strong base/nucleophile was introduced: Epoxide opening or the substitution reaction? An example is provided below of what I'm referring to:

[image]

If I perform, the epoxide ring opening, I get something unusual:

[image]

I left the stereochemistry ambigious because I honestly did not know how to assign it since a new stereocenter is formed.

If I perform the Sn2 substitution, the reaction is completed quickly:

[image]

Notice that both of my proposed mechanism reform the epoxide ring, but do generate entirely different structures.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/73398/how-to-rationalise-the-major-product-formed-in-a-nucleophile-promoted-epoxide-cl

Comment: I did not realize someone had posed a similar question. Thank you for the link.

Comment: Chloride isn't really that great a leaving group, either. The summary of this question is that two fast steps are collectively faster than one slow step.